# ResourceDictionary in App.xaml won't load

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a set of styles that I want to load to use as a StaticResource throughout my app: Styles.xaml

Everything works fine if I include the style in each window or page:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    <Window.Resources>        
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>        
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

If I try to include the style in my app resource, it throws an error that it can't find the MainWindow.xaml resource.

```
<Application x:Class="App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Anyone know why I can't include this in my app resource?

Comment: Can you try to restart Visual studio, I had similar issue.

Comment: @electricalbah restarted many times.  I've had issues with the VS2013 designer not playing nice with WPF and I think this is related.

Comment: I have almost the same problem in VS2015...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the MergedDictionary doesn't work, but if I add the style as a standalone resource it works fine.

```
<Application x:Class="App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Excavator"  
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml" />        
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would comment on your post but there's a 50 rep requirement...

Have you tried setting a key for the ResourceDictionary?

```
       <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Styles" Source="Resources/Styles.xaml" />
```

Comment: I tried that but for any namespace combination (x:Key, xmlns:Key, etc), I get "property key does not exist in XML namespace."

Comment: To clarify: all the individual styles inside Styles.xaml have a key.  I don't think the ResourceDictionary declaration requires a key.